# RegExp to match 10 lines or less, that's cross-compatible in Ruby and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a Rails backend that powers a Node frontend, and part of the Rails backend is validation on fields, that we than expose and pass to the Node frontend to consume.

Most of our validation rules are pretty simple things, blacklisting certain characters, etc.

But one rule is that a certain field can contain no more than 10 new lines.

Now, in Ruby this would be simple to achieve with the following:

```
/\A(^.*$\r?\n?){0,10}\z/
```

However, this is incompatible with Javascript, as the end of string and end of line characters are the same.

One way I tried which was compatible with both was the following:

```
/\A([^\n]*\n[^\n]*){10,}\z/
```

But whilst this worked fine on the Node side, this appears to be a case of [Catastrophic backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/863087/5946204) as if the test string gets too complicated, it takes exponentially longer to complete the Regular Expression.

I know this would be a *lot* simpler without using a Regular Expression, but due to the current setup of our stack, it is not an option to use anything than is not supported by the [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Any help would be greatly appreciated in this, as I'm banging my head into a brick wall trying to figure it out!

Comment: Neither `\A` nor `\z` mean anything special in JavaScript regular expressions; `\A` matches upper-case "A" and `\z` matches lower-case "z".

Comment: Also seems like "10 lines or less" would be `{0,10}` not `{10,}`.

Comment: Can you use a negative condition like "not 11 lines"? (in this case, build a pattern to match 11 lines, when the pattern succeeds return false, else return true). The main problem is the anchors `^` and `$` that have different meanings in Ruby and Javascript, and the fact that Javascript doesn't have the lookbehind feature.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with a single regex that will work in both JavaScript and Ruby.  Validating the entire contents of a string with a single regex match requires start-of-string and end-of-string anchors.  JavaScript and Ruby use incompatible syntax for these.

In JavaScript you can use `^` and `$` if you do not specify the `/m` flag to match the start and end of the string.  JavaScript does not support `\A` and `\z`.

In Ruby you can use `\A` and `\z` to match the start and end of the string.  Ruby does support `^` and `$` but does not have an option to make these match at the start and end of the string only.  They always match at embedded newlines.

The reason your regex devolves in to catastrophic backtracking is that you have `[^\n]*` at both the beginning and end of your repeated group.  This means that a non-LF character could be matched either by the second `[^\n]*` or by the first `[^\n]*` during the next iteration.  The regex engine will try all those permutations, which takes forever.

The solution is to have only one `[^\n]*` inside the group.  For JavaScript:

```
^[^\n]*(?:\n[^\n]*){0,10}$
```

For Ruby:

```
\A[^\n]*(?>\n[^\n]*){0,10}\z
```

Putting `\n` at the start of the group ensures that it fails immediately when either `[^\n]*` is backtracked.  In Ruby we can eliminate a lot of backtracking by using an atomic group.